# I cannot make this code work, it is a "type mismatch error"

Tags: vba, excel

Is there anything wrong with this code. I need to look through a column and if the value is less than a reference value (it is a timer) than copy adjacent cell and put in "A8".

Thanks.

```
Sub GetData()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 4 To 31

If Cells(i, 38) < Cells(32, 5) Then
Cells(1, 8) = Cells(i, 39)
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Possibly one of cell which you trying to compare results with error...

Comment: Why are you doing this in a loop? You are woverwriting `Cells(1,8) ` with every iteration of the loop.  My guess is that one or more of the cells you are comparing contains an error value, which is causing the mismatch.

Comment: @KazJaw +1 beat me by 8 seconds :)

Comment: @DavidZemens, but you beat my by length of your comment :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or alternatively to all presented options add this additional `If statement` before your existing `if`:

```
 If IsError(Cells(i, 39)) = False And IsError(Cells(32, 5))= False Then
```

Comment: That worked, but agreed it is overwriting. I am going to add a lot of ifs to counter that. I need to throttle information at certain times for an excel demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

you could try testing for a numeric value in the cell before testing for less than:

```
Sub GetData()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 4 To 31

  if isnumeric(cells(i,38)) then
    If Cells(i, 38) < Cells(32, 5) Then
        Cells(1, 8) = Cells(i, 39)
        ' Exit For ' UN-COMMENT to exit loop
    End If
  else
    msgbox "Cell '" & cells(i,38).address & "' may have an error",vbexclamation+vbokonly
  end if

Next

End Sub
```

BTW, the comments above by David and Kazjaw are quite right, every iteration of the loop you would potentionally overwrite cell A8!

You could exit the loop as soon as the test returns true like this:

`Exit for`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the mismatch, try comparing to the cell's text:

`If Cells(i,38).Text < Cells(32,5)...`